# Leanback create different custom Row Views

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I am using the Leanback library and I would like to know how to create multiple custom Row Views. For creating different items in a row you need to extend `PresenterSelector`

I tried doing the same for the `ListRowPresenter` but couldn't achieve the right result. 
No row was binded in the `RowsSupportFragment` and in the logs the `getPresenter` method from `PresenterSelector` was called multiple times until out of memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For solving this I had to check the [leanback showcase repository](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase)

Based on the class **[ShadowRowPresenterSelector](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/blob/d607fb3920e6e1b7801b95329e6df0e4e48f6118/app/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/supportleanbackshowcase/app/details/ShadowRowPresenterSelector.java)** I managed to find how to create a selector for my custom RowPresenters.

```
class ShadowRowPresenterSelector : PresenterSelector() {

    private val aCustomListRowPresenter by lazy { ACustomListRowPresenter() }
    private val bCustomListRowPresenter by lazy { BCustomListRowPresenter() }

    override fun getPresenter(item: Any): Presenter {
        return when (item) {
            is ARowVM -> {
                aCustomListRowPresenter
            }
            is BRowVM -> {
                bCustomListRowPresenter
            }
            else -> aCustomListRowPresenter
        }
    }

    override fun getPresenters(): Array<Presenter> {
        return arrayOf(aCustomListRowPresenter, bCustomListRowPresenter)
    }
}
```

What caused the method `getPresenter` to be called multiple times for me was that there I by mistake created every time a new object for my custom row presenter.

I hope this will help someone in the future.